How to define a static constructor within a JS class?
How do you define a static constructor within a JS class?
I managed to write something that somehow works but it requires to write a specific codepath in constructor for when an IngredientsDB object is instantiated from the static method IngredientsDB.fromXML():


class IngredientsDB {
  constructor(...args) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
      this.document = null;
    } else {
      this.document = new DOMParser().parseFromString("<ingredients/>", "text/xml");
      // ... process args
    }
  }
  static fromXML(xmlString) {
    const db = new this;
    db.document = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
    return db;
  }
  toString() { // concise output for testing
    const ingredientsNode = this.document.firstChild;
    let str = ingredientsNode.tagName + ":";
    let childNode;
    for (childNode of ingredientsNode.children)
      str += " " + childNode.tagName;
    return str;
  }
}

const xml = document.getElementById("ingredients").textContent.trimStart();
console.log(IngredientsDB.fromXML(xml).toString());
<script id="ingredients" type="text/xml">
<ingredients>
  <tomato/>
  <meat/>
  <cheese/>
</ingredients>
</script>




In your understanding, what is a "static constructor"? What are you actually trying to do?

@derpirscher Array.from() would be what I call a "static constructor", ie. a static method that creates a new Instance of the class it belongs to.

So in that understanding, how is your fromXML not a static constructor? It's a static method that creates a new Instance of IngredientsDB. Or in other words: How does your current code not work in the way you need it to?

@derpirscher It is, it works, and I don't feel it's right way to implement it.

Then, your question probably is better suited at https://codereview.stackexchange.com But I personally see nothing wrong with it ...

What are the arguments to the constructor used for? What does "process args" do?

These things are called "factory methods".

Is it really necessary to maintain a document property in your instance that has all the full-swing capabilities of event handlers, CSS, script elements, ...etc? That seems overkill.

@trincot Well, I'm still deciding how to write the whole thing; I need to load a XML file and do some queries on it at run time (keeping a DOMDocument and using XPath seems to the easiest way to do that); I also need to be able to build an analogous DB from scratch and export it as a XML string with the same XML scheme.

Apart from using static fromXML = function fromXML(xmlString) { instead of standard static fromXML(xmlString) { method syntax, there is nothing wrong with this code - that's exactly how to define a static factory method. Are you concerned about the db.document = … assignment and the initialisation of the property with null? Then just pass the document as an argument to the constructor!

@Bergi Good catch for the syntax ;-) Yeah, for example I would like to be able to raise an error when the constructor is called without the required arguments, unless it's from fromXML

Yeah don't do that "unless". Refactor your fromXML so that it calls the constructor with the required arguments, then throw an error if they're missing.

@Bergi I'd need to convert the XMLDOMDocument to  Objects/Arrays/Strings/Integers/Booleans/etc... before passing it to the constructor, which will rebuild exactly the same XMLDOMDocument... the XML file isn't that big but it still feels like a waste to do it that way.

@Fravadona Why that? Of course you can just pass the XMLDOMDocument as an argument, there is no arbitrary type restriction!

@Fravadona And further, you should consider removing that wasteful "rebuild the document" code from the constructor, and put that in a static factory method instead.

@Bergi Thanks for the advices; I don't know what I'll end-up writing as It's still an embryo of a project.

Btw, what is // ... process args doing? And how much similarity is there actually between IngredientsDB.fromXML(…) and new IngredientsDB(…) - currently the only difference I can see is that xmlString is defaulted to "<ingredients/>" if not passed?

@Bergi For now new IngredientsDB(…) takes an Array of "ingredients" (which are standard objects) and creates a new XMLDocument with them. That said, I'll also need at least an other "factory" method to create a subset an IngredientsDB from a given list of ingredient IDs

Does IngredientsDB do anything else than serialising a list of ingredients to a string? Does it have other methods? Does it have mutable state? Is it meant to be a wrapper around a (mutable) xml document and provides accessor (getter and setter) methods for it?

@Bergi Once an object of this class is instantiated it doesn't mute; it only has a few instance methods that hide XPath queries and one for exporting the DB as a XML string.

If it acts as a view onto an xml document, it should take that document as a constructor parameter and nothing else. It should have static helper methods for constructing (or preprocessing or validating) such documents (like xmlFromString), and/or static factory methods for creating views from various inputs (like fromXmlString). Maybe an "empty" document (or whole instance) if that's useful as well.

You can define a normal static method, do the XML parsing and pass the parsed arguments to the normal constructor, then return the constructed object.


class IngredientsDB {
  static fromXML(xml) {
    // parse the XML and extract the normal arguments
    const xmlDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
    const root = xmlDocument.documentElement;
    if (root.tagName === "ingredients") {
      const ingredients = Array.from(root.children, child => child.tagName);
      return new this(...ingredients);
    } else {
      return new this();
      // or throw new Error("expected root element <ingredients>");
    }
  }

  constructor(...ingredients) {
    // handle the arguments normally
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
  }

  toString() {
    // create string without the knowledge of the XML document
    return `ingredients: ${this.ingredients.join(" ")}`;
  }
}

const xml = document.getElementById("ingredients").textContent.trimStart();
console.log(IngredientsDB.fromXML(xml).toString());
console.log(new IngredientsDB("foo", "bar", "baz").toString());
<script id="ingredients" type="text/xml">
<ingredients>
  <tomato/>
  <meat/>
  <cheese/>
</ingredients>
</script>



Note this refers to the "receiver" of a method call. Which in the case of IngredientsDB.fromXML(xml) is IngredientsDB. You could also use IngredientsDB instead of this.

If a constructor does not allow for a specific scenario you could define instance methods that allow you to construct a specific instance and then alter the state.


class IngredientsDB {
  static fromXML(xml) {
    // parse the XML and extract the normal arguments
    const xmlDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
    const root = xmlDocument.documentElement;
    if (root.tagName === "ingredients") {
      const db = new this(); // assume we can't just pass the data through the constructor
      for (const child of root.children) db.addIngredient(child.nodeName);
      return db;
    } else {
      return new this();
      // or throw new Error("expected root element <ingredients>");
    }
  }

  constructor(...ingredients) {
    // handle the arguments normally
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
  }

  addIngredient(ingredient) {
    this.ingredients.push(ingredient);
  }

  toString() {
    // create string without the knowledge of the XML document
    return `ingredients: ${this.ingredients.join(" ")}`;
  }
}

const xml = document.getElementById("ingredients").textContent.trimStart();
console.log(IngredientsDB.fromXML(xml).toString());
console.log(new IngredientsDB("foo", "bar", "baz").toString());
<script id="ingredients" type="text/xml">
<ingredients>
  <tomato/>
  <meat/>
  <cheese/>
</ingredients>
</script>




So the idea would be to "unify" the normal constructor? I might be able to do something along those lines +1

@Fravadona Yes. Define the normal constructor in such a way that you can build "helpers" on top of them. This might mean that the default constructor is quite complex, but you can define another helper for common cases. Say for example you need a more complex constructor. You could define a helper fromArray() that simply takes an array, and does the assignment of the more complex arguments as part of its definition.

Alternatively you can call a simplified normal constructor, but assign the correct state by calling instance methods on the instance. Say for example that we parse the xml, then const db = new this(); then loop through the ingredients and add the ingredients, for (const root.children) db.addIngredient(child.nodeName); (assuming you have the method defined) and finally return the constructed object return db;
